# Name for geometry that differs by a translation

Tags: geometry, terminology

I have a simplistic question:  If I have two triangles, and there exists a translation that makes them equivalent (all their vertices would be the same after the translation), then is there a special term in geometry that I would use to describe the relationship between the two triangles?

Comment: I don’t think there is a word, but “translation-similar” is a reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that one triangle is the **translate** of the other. You could also say that they are **translationally equivalent**.

Answer (score 1):

They say the *translate*.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry):

"If $T$ is a translation, then the image of a subset $A$ under the function $T$ is the translate of $A$ by $T$. The translate of $A$ by $T_v$ is often written $A + v$."

Comment: In French, le *translaté*.

Answer (score 0):

A special case of  'Congruence of triangles':

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry).

I would simply say that a translation of $\triangle ABC$ along translation vector $\vec v$ results in the $\triangle A'B'C'$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is.

We say that the triangles (or shapes in general) are *congruent.* The relationship is known as **congruency.**

Comment: No, congruence allows rotation.

Comment: and congruence allows reflection.